# Application login code not working properly

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

i am having a problem when testing logging In (firebase), I am trying to login with email and password (firebase) and I set if else code,

If, login task is successful - It should show a "Success" toast message.
Else, It is should show "Failed" toast message.

I am building an admin application, so I need only one user account and I added my user account from firebase console.

When i try to login, App always shows "Failed" toast message even when login credentials matches my firebase login details.

Here is my Java Class :-

```
package com.appadmin;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email, pass;
    private Button login;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        pass = findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            //intent (i will add after firebase testing)
            return;
        }

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (email.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                email.setError("required!!");
                return;
            } else {
                email.setError(null);
            }

            if (pass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                pass.setError("required!!");
                return;
            } else {
                pass.setError(null);
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //this If body is not executing!
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

[Am using Email/password sign-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQpcH.png)

[with email link turned off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMD7e.png)

[Am getting this error on Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkubA.png)

Comment: Check the value of task.exception.message in the else block to see the reason why auth failed. Post the value here if you don't understand it.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, Sir am getting this line on run (when debugging) when i press Login Button - "I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@c4acfd".

Comment: If the task was not successful, log `task.getException()` to see what went wrong.

Comment: Now i added getExteption on else and got following error when logging in - "The given sign-in provider is disabled for this firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth Section" But Sir i have already enabled email and password sign in provider in Firebase console Check the image screenshots i provided in this question

Comment: You might be trying to connect to the wrong project. Check the google-services.json file in your android project and see if the project id is same as the one you posted in the screenshot. Or just download the google-services.json file from the firebase console and replace the existing one.

Comment: Please delete the screenshot as it reveals the keys for your project. Just download the file again and replace the existing one with it.

Comment: @AkshayJain Sir set-up new Firebase Config file but still it shows same error when i try to log-in.

Comment: It should not happen then. Try to disable and enable the email Auth in your firebase project.

Comment: Try out a few things - 1. Ensure you have created an app in the firebase project for the android app and the package id is right.  2. Try to disable and enable Auth. 3. Try to create a new android project with new package id, add the app to firebase project, then try the Auth.